# Split array into pairs and pack into object

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, object-notation

I have a an array with CSS text declarations like this: `['display: none ', 'opacity: 0.1', ' color: #ff0000']`

I want to split these into object key/value notation so it ends up like this:

```
{
  display: 'none',
  opacity: 0.1,
  color: '#ffffff'
}
```

*edit*: I've got a <s>working</s> wrong example, but it seems overly complicated and it doesnt serve the purpose (d'oh). Do you have a working one?

```
cssStyleDeclarations.map(function(item) {
  var x = item.split(':');
  var ret = {};
  ret[x[0].trim()] = x[1].trim();

  return ret;
});
```

It returns it as array with an object for each entry (`[Object, Object, Object]`), but I want it as a pure object.

Comment: doesn't seem overly complicated to me...

Comment: I agree, it's simple and effective.

Comment: Nvm, it didn't even work right. I got back an array of objects, but it should just serve an object with key/value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `Array.prototype.reduce()`:

```js
var input = ['display: none ', 'opacity: 0.1', ' color: #ff0000'];

var css = input.reduce((p, c) => {
  var x = c.split(':');
  p[x[0].trim()] = x[1].trim();
  return p;
}, {});

console.log(css);
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's what I wanted. Thanks!